# Show a new GIF on each page visit or page reload

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, gif, giphy

I'm using the GIPHY api to display an image based on a query. Below is the code I'm currently using to pull the image. It works but the problem right now is that each time you visit the website it shows the same GIF every visit until the query changes. What I'd like is for the GIF to update after every visit or page reload to a new random image in the array even if the query is the same. I'm really new to javascript and am unsure how to solve this problem so any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the function I'm using to query data

```
function weather(position) {
  var apiKey = '';
  var url = '';
  var data;
  // console.log(position);
  $.getJSON(url + apiKey + "/" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "?callback=?", function(data) {

    $('.js-current-item1').html(Math.floor(data.currently.temperature) + '&#176;');
    $('.js-current-item2').html(data.currently.summary);

    gif(data.currently.icon)
    city(position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude)

  });
}
```

And here is the function for pulling images from GIPHY

```
function gif(status) {
  var apiKey = '';
  var url = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=';
  var query = status;
  $.getJSON(url + query + apiKey, function(data) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.data[5].images.original.url + ')');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function gif(status) while setting the image choose a random value from data array instead of fixed

change

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.data[5].images.original.url + ')');
```

to

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.data.length);
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.data[randomIndex].images.original.url + ')');
```